# PDO problems - call to member function query() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to switch over to PDO and I'm having some trouble..

I get an error saying "call to member function query() on a non-object" whenever I hit the foreach loop (i'm going to take a wild guess and say that for some reason $dbc is coming up blank?).

I know that a lot of this kind of question has been asked and I've spent a long time going through answers but I still am having trouble.

I'm pretty new to all of this, so there's probably some kind of obvious mistake I'm making but any help would be appreciated.

NOW FIXED : I simply forgot to -actually call- the function I laid out. Code below now works.

```
$DBNAME = 'myDatabase';
$HOST   = 'myHost';
$USER   = 'myUser';
$PASS   = 'myPassword';


function dbconnect($DBNAME, $HOST, $USER, $PASS) {
    try {
        global $dbc;
        $dbc = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$DBNAME;host=$HOST", $USER, $PASS);
        $dbc->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } 
    catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

}
dbconnect($DBNAME, $HOST, $USER, $PASS);

$tQuery =
            'select
             adm.TalentCode,
             adm.Paid,
             adm.Comp,
             tl.CaVO,
             tl.TxVO,
             tl.LaVO,
             tnd.FirstName,
             tnd.LastName,
             tp.Thumbnail

             from

             AdminTalentData as adm
             inner join TalentLocale as tl using(TalentCode)
             inner join TalentNameData as tnd using(TalentCode)
             inner join TalentPhoto as tp using(TalentCode)
             where adm.Paid = 0 || adm.Comp = 0';

foreach($dbc->query($tQuery) as $r)
{    
    //create a table from the results
}
```

Thanks in advance and I'll be happy to provide any more necessary info if need be.

Comment: You're not calling `dbconnect();` in your code?

Comment: You can't use || as or in SQL, has to be 'OR', try that. Also, you need to either remove the function or call dbconnect(), before you query. The latter is preferred. Also, I might return the $dbc so you can use it in your foreach.

Comment: You don't seem to call `dbconnect()` anywhere.

Comment: Oh my god. I forgot to call the function I laid out. Everything works now... thanks for the time, guys. Sorry for wasting it.

Answer (score 0):

$ dbc is not within your variabel scope. This is part of php variable scoping and not pdo related.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php